# Regex capture groups in Sieve script

Tags: regex, dovecot, sieve-language

I want to put emails that are forwarded to my main mailbox (from another domain) into specific sub-folders. For example: `foo@bar` goes to `INBOX/bar/foo`.

```
require ["fileinto", "envelope", "regex", "mailbox"];

if header :regex "delivered-to" "(.*)@(.*)" {
    if not envelope :is "to" "${1}@${2}" {
        fileinto :create "INBOX/${2}/${1}";
    }
}
```

The capture groups are not replaced in `INBOX/${2}/${1}`, why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match group variables are not part of the `regex` capability, but the [`variables` capability](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5229#section-3.2). Also `require ["variables"];` to be able to use them.

Comment: Is there a way to replace dots with underscore in a variable?

Comment: This does not really seem a direct follow-up question to your original question but a new one, please ask an actual new question instead of discussing it in the comments.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna have to wait 50 minutes to do that, for whatever reason...